# How to specify number of instances in UML Class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Is there a way in a UML class diagram to indicate how many instances of a given class will be present in your system?

I know you can indicate the multiplicity of a relationship between classes:

```
Dog * ----------- 1 Yard 1 ----------- * Tree
```

But is there a common way to visually depict that there is exactly say, five instances of Yard in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot  express this directly with UML bit with OCL (Object Constraint Language). It would be an invariant of Yard like

```
context Yard inv: Yard.allInstances()->size()=5
```

OCL is a language designed to express formal constraints when modelling with UML.

Comment: Instead of OCL you can also use a simple constraint like `{ there must be 5 instances }` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this explanation on UML multiplicities](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html), it is perfectly valid to use any  natural numbers for the number of elements. Also, if the lower bound is equal to the upper bound, you can describe them by using just one number (e.g. `1..1` is equivalent to `1`)

So you can for example have:

```
Yard 1 ----------- 5 Tree
```